# scipy.optimize.curve_fit() not passing 2d data correctly

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a 2d function to an array using curve_fit() but I am having some trouble with the `ydata` parameter.
(Basically my function is trying to fit two 2d slopes to the data, one over the whole dataset and a second that is flat up to a point defined by `div1, div2`.)

Here is my code:

```
def two_slope_regression((X1,X2), data, div1, div2):
    #Set up parameters
    m = 1016
    print 'data', data
    print 'data type', type(data)
    div1 = int(div1)
    div2 = int(div2)
    print 'div1, div2', div1, div2
    X1div = np.zeros_like(X1)
    X2div = np.zeros_like(X2)
    X1div[div1:] = X1[div1:]
    X2div[div2:] = X2[div2:]
    Y = np.array(data)

    #Regression
    X = np.hstack((np.reshape(X1, (m*m, 1)), np.reshape(X2, (m*m, 1)),
               np.reshape(X1div, (m*m, 1)), np.reshape(X2div, (m*m, 1))) 
             )
    X = np.hstack((np.ones((m*m, 1)), X))
    YY = np.reshape(Y, (m*m, 1))
    theta = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(np.dot(X.transpose(), X)), X.transpose()), YY)
    print 'theta', theta

    y = theta[0] + theta[1]*X1 + theta[2]*X2 + theta[3]*X1div + theta[4]*X2div
    return y.ravel()

def fit_slope(data):
    m=1016
    print 'data type', type(data)
    X1, X2 = np.mgrid[:m, :m]
    print 'data shape', data.shape
    #init_guess = (508, 508)
    popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(two_slope_regression, xdata=(X1,X2), ydata=data)#, p0=(508,508))
    print 'popt, pcov', popt, pcov
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    theta_samp = np.random.rand(5)
    x1,x2 = np.mgrid[:1016, :1016]
    x1div = np.zeros_like(x1)
    x1div[508:] = x1[508:]
    x2div = np.zeros_like(x2)
    x2div[508:] = x2[508:]
    sample_data = np.random.randn(1016, 1016)*theta_samp[0] + theta_samp[1]*x1 + theta_samp[2]*x2 + theta_samp[3]*x1div + theta_samp[4]*x2div    
    fit_slope(sample_data)
```

As you can see, I have included `print` statements to check the type and shape of the data array at different stages. The first time is in `fit_slope()` - the type is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and the shape is `(1016,1016)`. So far so good. 
The second time is when `curve_fit()` calls `two_slope_regression()` and it outputs `data 1.0` and `data type <type 'numpy.float64'>` before the error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1032256,1)`.

So somehow the `ydata` parameter is not being passed to the fit function properly. Any ideas what is going wrong?

I don't know if this is relevant, but I was having another problem earlier with the `p0` parameter (now commented out). When I tried to pass the fit parameters I got the following error:

```
TypeError: two_slope_regression() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

As far as I can tell I am using `curve_fit()` as the documentation requires. What I am missing?

Comment: Could you provide some input data?

Comment: how does your `two_slope_regression()` get `div1` and `div2`? Those are required arguments but you are not passing them in from `curve_fit`.

Comment: I just added some randomly generated data.

Comment: `div1` and `div2` should be passed in `p0` but `curve_fit()` didn't like the number of arguments I passed to it. Perhaps this is related to the problem, I don't know. For now, they are initialized by default to `1.0`, just like `ydata`.

Comment: The fuction to fit in `curve_fit` shall not take the `yData` as arg. `curve_fit` only checks the least square difference. So you call `curfe_fit( func(xData, yData)` If `func` is of type `func(x, a,b,c)` `curve_fit` will call it with `func( xData, aFit, bFit, cFit)` as it figures out the required number of parameters itself. By making `yData` an arg of the fit function it as totally 4 paramters i.e. `x, y, div1, div2` but with `p0=(508,508)`  it receives from `curve_fit` only `x, 508, 508` i.e. 3 parameters. Moreover, `curve_fit` cannot handle parameters that a fixed, it considers all variable

Comment: ...just read it again... the 3 parameters it sees now are probably `X1, X2, yData`.  However, I think you should stop thinking about this problem and start from scratch as your entire fitting procedure seems to be messed up. What is it that you actually want to fit? What is the set of not fixed parameters? Are there fixed parameters? Is `curve_fit` the right tool?